# Show that $P(x,y)=0$ is a hyperbola if $b^2−4ac>0$ .

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, conic-sections, plane-curves

The following exercise is from Thomas Garrity's Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach.

> Suppose $b^2-4ac>0$.
>
> $(1)$ Show that one of the following occurs: $\{y\ |∆_x(y)\ge 0\} =\mathbb R$ and $∆_x(y)\ne 0,\ \{y\ |∆_x(y)=0\}=\{y_o\}$ and $\{y\ |∆_x(y)>0\}=\{y\ |\ |y|>y_o\}$, or there exist real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $\alpha<\beta$, such that $\{y\ |∆_x(y)\ge 0\}= \{y\ |\ y\le\alpha\}\cup\{y\ |\ y\ge\beta\}$.
>
> $(2)$ Show that if there exist real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $\alpha<\beta$, such that $\{y\ |∆_x(y)\ge 0\}=\{y\ |\ y\le \alpha\}\cup\{y\ |\ y\ge \beta\}$, then $V(P)$ is a hyperbola.

I write the polynomial $P(x, y) = ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+h$ in the form $P(x, y) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$ where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are polynomial functions of $y$. This $P(x, y) = Q(x)$ has the discriminant $\Delta_x(y) = (b^2 − 4ac)y^2 + (2bd − 4ae)y + (d^2 − 4ah)$. And I stuck!

Any hint to start solving this?

Comment: Isn’t this more or less the same problem that you’ve already attacked in previous questions with different values of the discriminant?

Comment: @amd, Some remarks: 1- I am a member of MSE for less than a month, and my experience to this day is that anytime I've tried to ask only a *little* more/different question I've been replied like why don't you ask it as a new post? And this question would've been much longer if I had posted all three discriminant cases in one single question so most probably even worse replies.. Also, answers (= resulting sets to be explained) are different. 2- I introduced $\Delta_x(y)$, etc for better clarifications because may not anyone who reads this question reads also any other previous questions.